# function issue in appcelerator titanium

Tags: javascript, appcelerator-titanium

In My app i am calling function like below but toJSDate function not invoked. What is the problem can anyone tell why.

In console i get only getIssueProgress Called.

Below i am sharing code.

```
function toJSDate(){
      Ti.API.info('getIssueProgress Called');
}
function getIssueProgress() {
    Ti.API.info('getIssueProgress Called');
    var check_Date = toJSDate('anil');
}
```

Comment: without calling how get info from getIssueProgress(). That one also i need to include

Answer (score 0):

your `toJSDate()` doesn't expect a parameters but your calling it with a parameter `var check_Date = toJSDate('anil');`. Remove `'anil'`:

```js
function toJSDate(){
    console.log('toJSDate');
   //Ti.API.info('getIssueProgress Called');
}
function getIssueProgress() {
    console.log('getIssueProgress');
    //Ti.API.info('getIssueProgress Called');
    var check_Date = toJSDate();//not: toJSDate('anil');
}

getIssueProgress();
```

If you do want to pass that parameter you need to add it to the function declaration

```js
//add parameter here
function toJSDate(param){
    console.log('toJSDate');
    console.log(param);
   //Ti.API.info('getIssueProgress Called');
}
function getIssueProgress() {
    console.log('getIssueProgress');
    //Ti.API.info('getIssueProgress Called');
    var check_Date = toJSDate('anil');
}

getIssueProgress();
```